# How to change the icon in the pkg when using jpackage?

Tags: java, javafx, jpackage

On Os X, when using the jpackage command line tool, how to setup the icon used in the pkg file? Is there an additional property which can be set?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally don't use the PKG format so I don't know this myself but did you look into the documentation here [override-jpackage-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6)? This section is dedicated to such questions.

Comment: What is the command?